# Unable to navigate from RootContainer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

In my App.js file I have a RootContainer wrapped by Provider tags.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import RootContainer from './screens/RootContainer';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

In the RootContainer I render the MainNavigator, and I also check AsyncStorage with an action for a token. If there is a token, which there is, I want to navigate to another screen which is where I am having trouble.

```
import actions, connect, createBottomTabNavigator, etc.

class RootContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() { this.props.checkForToken(); } // dispatch async action, success, token found 

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { this.authComplete(nextProps); }

  authComplete(props) {
    if(props.token) { // success, token exists 
      props.navigation.navigate('map'); // undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')
// this.props.navigation.navigate('map); does not work either.
    }
  }

  render() { 
    return ( <MainNavigator /> ); // loads fine when navigation route is commented out 
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => { return { token: auth.state.token } };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(RootContainer);
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

I was trying to call `this.props.navigation.navigate` inside RootContainer, but `this.props.navigation` is only available inside screen components.

Solution - move checkForToken logic to a screen component instead of RootContainer. Viola!